# How to create a tabbar controller similar to iOS tabbarController in jqueryMobile correctly?

Tags: jquery, html, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a `tabbar` controller in `jquery-mobile`, but I fellow the demo of `jquery-mobile` api:http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/tabs/#&ui-state=dialog failed:

The result become this:

> [image: there are two issue]

You see, there is two issue here:

1) the `three` is offset down of the level.
2) I want the `navbar`(in `iOS` called `tabbar`) locate in the bottom of `page`.

My code is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!--<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charse=utf-8">-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../js/lib/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<footer data-position="fixed">
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#one" data-ajax="false">one</a></li>
          <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">two</a></li>
          <li><a href="ajax-content-ignore.html" data-ajax="false">three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
        <h1>First tab contents</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="two">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this could help you https://framework7.io/

Comment: @Ponja I don't think this is fit the `jquery-mobile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using navbar plugin this way:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
         <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
         </div>
         <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>My Content..</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac metus at quam consectetur feugiat. Quisque blandit vulputate turpis, eu molestie sem dapibus id. Etiam mattis odio quam, id facilisis nisi commodo ac. Duis orci ex, auctor vitae mi quis, elementum dictum leo. Fusce ullamcorper dignissim justo, at facilisis velit facilisis vitae. Sed quis efficitur lorem. Integer in molestie felis. Maecenas cursus tempor consequat. Aliquam dapibus accumsan aliquet. Donec non eleifend mauris. Fusce vitae efficitur purus. Aenean sed imperdiet nibh, et tristique lorem. Donec volutpat sem orci, vel ornare sapien tempus ut. Pellentesque lacinia, libero ac tincidunt vulputate, tortor leo placerat ipsum, ut finibus sem est a nunc. Praesent quis condimentum dolor.
            </p>
         </div>
         <div data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="navbar">
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#pageone">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#pagetwo">Page Two</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#search">Search</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
         <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Welcome To Page Two</h1>
         </div>
         <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>This is page two!</p>
         </div>
         <div data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="navbar">
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#pageone">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#pagetwo">Page Two</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#search">Search</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="page" id="search">
         <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Welcome To SEARCH PAGE</h1>
         </div>
         <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>SEARCH!</p>
         </div>
         <div data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="navbar">
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#pageone">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#pagetwo">Page Two</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#search">Search</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I saw, I tested. and my requirement is also when click `Home`, `Page Two`, and `Search`, I want to switch the page, how to do with that? if you make that detail, this must be a upvoted answer.